# Tint single letter in LibGDX GlyphLayout or Label?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a possibility to tint a single letter of a String for the GlyphLayout or Label in LibGDX?

Answer (score 1):

**BitmapFontCache**, Caches glyph geometry for a BitmapFont.

```
BitmapFont bitmapFont=new BitmapFont();
BitmapFontCache bitmapFontCache=new BitmapFontCache(bitmapFont);
```

BitmapFontCache having `setColors (float color, int start, int end)` method that sets the color of the specified characters.

Comment: Thank you that works. Is there a possibility how to set this BitmapFontCache into a label? So, I would like to add an Actions.moveTo() effect for the text, therefore I actually need a label. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use **Color Markup Language**, which is built into LibGDX.

You just have to enable markup language like this:

```
BitmapFont font = myfont;
font.getData().markupEnabled = true;
```

then you simple format your text as follows:

```
String text = "[RED]My test string[]"
```

This also works for labels :)

Pretty good read on this topic: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language